# Debug .NET com dll when running from Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, com

I have a com dll developed in VB.net that provides an interface to eBay api's. Been working for many years. Recently eBay change certificate authority and moved to TLS 1.2. Sorted through that but now the dll seems to quit in mid transaction when called from Access. The functionality does listings from local inventory to eBay. The first part loads pictures of the listing item to eBay. That works fine. I can see the calls and responses using Fiddler. It then moves on to actually listing the item which seems to stop when called from Access. What I get back in Access is "Can't find x.dll at file location". I know the call is going to the dll because it uploads the pictures.

I have a test project developed in VB.net to test the dll and when run from that everything works. I can see the listing call and response in fiddler. When run from Access there is no listing call. I can verify that the endpoints for the calls are the same from test project or Access.

My question is how to debug the dll in the Visual Studio IDE when it is called from Access. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the way you do this is open up the vs class you have for the .dll.

Then in debug of the project, setup this:

[image]

Now, when you hit f5, then access will launch and run.

If at this point, say you close access (exit), then you note the debugging process stops.

However, go though the forms and whatever in Access, and get to the point where you hit that button or whatever.

You find now that you can say set a break point and even step and debug your .net code like any other code. So say in my example (a custom sage 300 .net interface to access), I want to debug "find customer" routine from VBA.

Well, in vb.net I have this code:

[image]

so, when any routine - even those in the class instances is called, you can set break-points etc.

And to stop? Just exit access.

So, you can make a change to your code, and even hit f5.

It not clear how you are registering your .dll (or do you use some VBA to side-load the .net - that's what I do, since it is a pain to have to register my .net com objects on each PC.

But, do give the above a try. It should let you debug your .dll code. The trick is to have VS launch ms-access as a attached debug session - and that is exactly what the above setting in your class project above allows you to do.

do note in above, I used the path to access 2010 (access 14), so replace the path name to the access.exe with your version of access you are using.

And keep in mind, that if have some installer, or some custom "thing" that registers your .net .dll for you?

Well, during this process, if your VBA assumes a registered com object, then ensure you have this check box enabled:

On compile for the project settings, you thus want this option checked:

[image]

NOTE very careful, checking the above option does not change the code or anything at all - it ONLY does a regasum automatic for you, and this would of course re-register your existing .dll  - which is what we want for debugging. After you done, do run your re-register of your .dll to switch back from the debug .dll that going to be in your current project bin folder to whatever you "regular" use on your PC.

FYI:
In MOST cases, I find this whole idea does NOT work unless you launch VS as administraor. So, make sure VS is being run as administraor for this to work.

I tend to just tap windows key, or even right click on your vs shortcut, and  of course choose run as administraor.

This is so often required, you note that VS will EASY and quite CLEAR show you running in admin mode, and I quite much now always run VS this way.

You should see this:

[image]

Comment: Once again, thank you Albert. I tried that but didn't understand the process. I tried starting from Access. this will help so much.

Comment: No, you let vs run and it will launch Access for you. So if you setup debug like screen shot then just hit f5 in vs. It will launch ms-access for you. But since vs launched ms-access then you get in process debugging. You don't launch or start ms-access, vs will do that. So close and exit ms-access before you try above

Comment: So you open the vs project used to create that DLL. Setup the debug info as per above and then f5 in vs- it will launch ms-access. You can now single step and set break points in the.net code.

Comment: Albert, In your description above you said "It not clear how you are registering your .dll (or do you use some VBA to side-load the .net - that's what I do, since it is a pain to have to register my .net com objects on each PC." I'd like a little more information on what you do here. As you say having to register and re-register dll's is a pain. Thanks, Doug.

Comment: The register for com opt screen in above is ONLY for use on your development computer.  Checking that option in NO WAY changes ANYTHING in regards to the final com object. So, in regards to deployment on different computers? No, if you side loading, then you don't care nor have any regasm required. So, for deployment use, then only requirement is that the simple .dll is placed in the same location as the access front end. With side loading, it assumes .dll will be in same folder and we load it - and thus it can be used. So, I build a side loader in .net, and from VBA it loads the .dll

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the term sideloading. Do you mean you have code using "AddFromFile", or do you just put the dll file in the same directory as the access application and let it find it?

Comment: We talking about consuming and using external .dll's from VBA. So, from VB we go tools-.refrences and set a refernce to that .dll. But, those external .dll's (written in c#, vb.net, or even c++ or even VB6) of course have to be registered on the computer before such external .dll's can be used from VBA. But, with locked down computers, then we often can't register such extremal COM objects, and worse they have to be registered on the computer. With sideloading, we don't have to register that external .dll in question, but "side load" the .dll.

Comment: So, having to register such external .dll's to be used (called) from VBA is a pain. So, with sideloading, we ONLY have to place that external .dll in the same folder as access, and we don't have to set a reference to the dll (we use late binding), but the really big issue is that with sideloading, we also don't have to register that external. .dll on each computer - which is the painful part. So this post and answer is in that context - we calling vb.net code from VBA - but we don't want the pain of having to register that .net .dll on each computer - quite much means to use a installer.

Comment: So, with side loading, we only have to place that external .net .dll in the same folder as the Access front end, and we are done - no registering (regsvr32.exe, or regasm.exe) of the .dll is thus required. So, we not talking about consuming or using VBA code, this is about using and calling external .dll code - in this case .net code. With this setup, then I am able with great ease to incorporate .net code into my VBA/Access applications - that was the WHOLE context and answer in this question.

Comment: You already stated here in the comments that you already are side loading and consuming .net external .dll's this way - unless you actually meant something else. If  you callling and using and consuming .net code from VBA as you stated you are, then you don't need my side loader approach, but then you must be using something to consume that .net code and external .dll's then, right? How can we have a conversation  about this and you stating your already doing this - that is also what I am doing also. There are several ways to consume + use those external .dll code libraries from VBA.

Comment: the most common way to do this from VBA is to create a instance of the .net runtime in VBA code (I don't do that). So creating a instance of the .net runtime in VBA - you loading the .net runtime "on the side", hence the term side-loading. As stated, I don't actually do that since the examples floating around on the web also require a few additonal references in VBA - and I don't and did not want those extra references (broken references always a pain, right???). So, I use a different approach, but called it side loading since that is what I assume you are already doing and you stated as such.

Comment: I mean, if  you not registering the .net .dll you created, then how are you using it? As noted, I don't want to have to register those .dll's on each computer. These days, most computers are locked down, and to register the .dll on each computer is a pain, so with side loading, we don't have to. Only requirement is to place the .dll in the same location as the VBA front end, and we load + use + consume + call that .net code without going though the pain and hassle of having to register the external .net library on each computer. Only requirement is the simple placing of the .net .dll in folder

Comment: And the VBA front end does not just FIND that .dll, we specific load the .dll in VBA code and then are free to call the routines in that .dll. So, I adopted the standard that the .dll is to be placed in the same location as the Access front end applcation. So, we assume and load the .net .dll based on current location, load the .dll, and then we are now free to use that external COM object in our VBA code - but we removed the hassle of having that .dll being registered on each computer. Whole lot less  hassle with just the requirement of dropping the .dll in same location as our FE.

Comment: I currently register the dll, which as you say is a pain, and sometimes is not possible for security reasons. I am trying to understand how you do your side load. On my development machine the dll is registered on compiling so that is easy. But I would like to understand your technique for other machines where the dll is not registered. I may not have asked the question clearly but do you use the vba References.AddFromFile method to reference your dll file?

Comment: Ah, ok, so I misunderstood you. Yes, you most certainly want simple copy deployment. Locked down computers and having to register such .dll often requires elevated rights and that's a pain. So yes, you most certainly want to setup a way to just use and consume those DLLs and do so with great ease and without having to register those DLLs. I have an working example of this and a sample that allows access to merge PDF files and it's registration free. You can find that example here http://www.kallal.ca/Articles/Pdf/Merge.html

Comment: I am experimenting with LoadLibrary. I looked at your program and tested the LoadLib function in a test Access application to see if it would load my dll. When I run the test LoadLibrary(CurrentProject.Path & "\" & "eBayListing.dll") returns a value not 0. But when I try and create an object from the loaded dll I get "nothing". After running if I look at the project references my dll isn't listed. On my development machine when I build the dll project it registers it on the machine. In looking at what is registered it is the .tlb file, not the .dll file. The tlb file gives and error in loadLib

Comment: You don't need the tlb file - only the dll. Your have to get the class name correct. AND YOU DO NOT HAVE to set a reference in VBA - in fact for outlook, Excel, or any automation in VBA,  you NEVER want to deploy with that VBA reference - it will break and cause havoc at deployment time. Look up late binding vs early binding in VBA. You ALWAYS want to remove the VBA references - that applies to using word, Excel, or in this case your .dll. You LATE bind, and don't deploy with VBA references. This is a long time survival rule for all VBA developers. So no tlb file and no registering is required

Comment: I mean, if my sample worked, did it have a tlb file? (nope!!). Did the sample run, and use that .net com object? (yes). Did I have a reference in VBA code? (nope). You don't want to deploy your applications with VBA references unless you have no choice. This applies when access is using Excel, Word, outlook - any application, and this good long time rule ALSO includes the use case of your custom com objects. You can develop with early binding, but at deployment time, such automation code should use late binding - quite much a assumption I have made here.

Comment: look close at the sample. The loadlibrary uses nloader. We then create the object. You don't ever change the name of nloader, but of course do pass the .net dll to load when you use the CreateObjectNET. Remember, we simple swap out our CreateObject() VBA command for CreateObjectNET. If your code works as late binding with CreateObject(), then the nloader should be able to load your .dll as a COM object. Get your code working with CreateObject FIRST, once done, swap out CreateObject, and use CreateObjectNet. If your code dont work with VBA createobject(), then createObjectNET also not work

Comment: Using CreateObject in VBA thus means no VBA reference is required. However, on your dev box, CreateObject() in VBA WILL require that the .dll is registered. However, your not have that VBA reference. If your code works with VBA createObject, then CreateObjectNET should now also work, but you now don't need the .dll to have been registered.

Comment: Hi Albert. I finally found a spelling error in my test application. Object loading seems to be working well now. I am adding to my Access application. Thank you for your assistance and support of our community.

Comment: All good. Of course with late binding, then we have to be MUCH more careful, since we don't get inteli-sense, and don't get compile time checking of what we type in. As noted, if you come across ariticles in regards to late binding, then they often will suggest that you can develop as early. You then drop the dim myCool as myCoolcom.myCoolcom and replace that with dim myCool as Object, and then use create object. So, testing, running, development can occur with early binding. Once all bugs gone, then you try as late binding. (but, then caution - since any typeo can fail).

Comment: Also, the MAIN reason for that pdf merge post was the long time Stephan Lebans PDF merge code does not work as x64 bits, so the community needed a solution. You can in most cases compile the .net code as "ANY" cpu, and the one .dll can thus be used from either access x32, or access x64. (however, if access x64, then nloader xt64 version is required. In the past, I have in most cases forced compile the .net code to x86, and x64 versions. Being short of time, I have wanted to do more testing, but so far the information I have suggests that the .net project can be used with ANY CPU.

Comment: Yes, I have my application set up with compiler constants to use early binding during development and late binding for deployment.